# multiple css @media (max-width:) not working

Tags: css

Wondering if anyone can help me,
I am trying to have multiple @media but the last @media I do overrides the other ones.
so the max-width 768px overrides max-width 375..

```
/* Banner */
@media (max-width: 375px) {
.jumbotron {
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 278px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.banner_title {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.banner_para {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.banner_btn {
  font-size: 15px;
}

}

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
.jumbotron {
  height: 378px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.banner_title {
  font-size: 80px;
}

.banner_para {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.banner_btn {
  font-size: 18px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS the order in which your code is executed is from the top to the bottom. It's called cascading I will place a link below for more info about it.

In your case, a maximum is set to `375px` and `768px`. If your viewport is `300px` it's maximum is in rang of the `375px` and the `768px` you defined. So CSS will look at the order of which the code is defined.

Example (viewport 300px):

```
@media (max-width: 375px) { 
   body { background-color: red; }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
   body { background-color: blue; }
}
```

`300px` is below `375px` and `768px`. So it passes (like an if-statement) max of `375px` and `768px`. The last defined body color is **blue**!

If you still want the same code to work, make sure the lowest value is placed last:

Example (viewport 300px):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
   body { background-color: red; }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) { 
   body { background-color: blue; }
}
```

My personal recommendation is switching to min-width values instead of max. More about this: http://www.the-haystack.com/2015/12/23/choosing-between-min-and-max-width/

More about cascading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the css code in the same sequence just by adding min-width to media query as well. look at the below css code:

```
    /* Banner */
@media (min-width: 122px)and (max-width: 375px) {
.jumbotron {
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 278px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.banner_title {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.banner_para {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.banner_btn {
  font-size: 15px;
}

}

@media (min-width: 376px)and(max-width: 768px) {
.jumbotron {
  height: 378px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.banner_title {
  font-size: 80px;
}

.banner_para {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.banner_btn {
  font-size: 18px;
}
}
```

Now you don't need to change the order of the css code. Alter the min-width size according to your requirement.